# Retrofit, nested JSON object as collection

Tags: json, retrofit, retrofit2, jsonschema

Let's say I have a JSON:

```
{
    "age" : 26,
    "email" : "norman@futurestud.io",
    "isDeveloper" : true,
    "name" : "Norman",
    "userAddress" : {
       "city" : "Magdeburg",
       "country" : "Germany",
       "houseNumber" : "42A",
       "street" : "Main Street"
    }
}
```

I`m using Retrofit and jsonschema2pojo. 
For userAdress, it generates a class with four fields. Is it possible to store userAddress content as a HashMap of two Strings instead of separate class?

Comment: Could you post some code in order to get a better understanding of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) JSON convertor library.

Create a Java class (use the same class if you've already created). (For testing purpose I've created a class called `User`)

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.Map;

public class User {

  @SerializedName("age")
  private int age;
  @SerializedName("email")
  private String email;
  @SerializedName("isDeveloper")
  private boolean isDeveloper;
  @SerializedName("name")
  private String name;
  @SerializedName("userAddress")
  private Map<String, String> userAddress;

  // other member variables if any

  // constructors if any

  // getter and setter methods

}
```

If you want to convert JSON into POJO manually, here is the sample usage of the above class.

```
String jsonData = "your_json_data_received_from_api";
User user = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, User.class);
// do whatever you want to with user object
```

Or if you want convert JSON into POJO internally using Retrofit, don't worry about that. Retrofit will handle it internally.

But make sure that you're using right JSON `key` in `@SerializedName()` annotation inside the POJO (model) class.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Happy coding :)